# How to make sure all necessary libraries will be included on every system?

Tags: c

I have been going down the `fstat()` rabbit hole. Apparently you need `sys/stat.h`, but the stat struct needs a bunch of weird types like dev_t, ino_t, mode_t, nlink_t, uid_t, gid_t, off_t, blksize_t, blkcnt_t, which are apparently in `sys/types.h`.

Ok, but the stat struct has 3 more timespec structs in itself, which use time_t and need `time.h`

In the code examples, sometimes you can't print these values without wrapping them in some third type, which requires inclusion of even more headers.

So my question is how do I make sure that `sys/stat.h` does include the necessary `time.h` header? And if it works on my system, how to make sure it will work on another that maybe has a different stat header, or different system functions?

Do I just include all the redundant headers for the types I need and trust the header guards to do their thing, or do I rely on the libraries actually pulling the things they need themselves? But how can I do that if the man page says explicitly to include `sys/types.h` because stat DOESN'T pull them?

This is not necessarily a specific question for my problem. I am hoping for some easy way to check if inclusion of specific libraries is standard, or if there is a chance that it is system-specific.

Comment: You should only need to include whatever the manual page says you need to include to use a particular function and its results. It is up to the implementation to ensure any dependent types are also defined with just the specified headers explicitly included.

Comment: You should only need to make sure that used libraries are installed on any PC you want to run and/or compile your code.

Comment: To be clear, you are distributing this code to be compiled on different systems?

Comment: Rather than ensuring that all the necessary dependencies are installed, your build should simply abort if they are not available.  Then the package management system (eg `rpm` (or `yum`) or `pkg` or `dpkg` or (`apt`)) can be used to handle dependency management.

Comment: You could define a suitable [feature test macro](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02) before including any header files to cause `#include <sys/stat.h>` to define more types without having to include `<sys/types.h>` separately.

Comment: I tried to prove kaylum wrong by commenting out sys/types.h from my code, and the program compiled fine. Now I can't find the man page where it explicitly said to include sys/types.h before sys/stat.h because it defines dev_t. To be fair, though, every single example, both in stat(2) and stat(3) includes both.
So, what do you suggest I do? How do I even know which headers i SHOULD include, if I don't get an error on my system?
Oh, I just remembered: the Windows version said explicitly to always use sys/types.h